# Google Maps strange green texture when zooming in

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, google-maps

On my tablet Lenovo 10" Android 4.2.2 my Google Maps looks really annoying, when I zoom in it has this green texture covering the map. Anyone knows why this happens and how to get rid of it? Google Maps is up to date.

[image: green color overlaying the landmass]
T

EDIT : It is also awfully slow and it takes seconds to respond to touch and zoom.

EDIT 2 : Its only the app, in the Browser (Chrome) it works well.

EDIT 3 : Got it back to normal, by uninstalling updates, deactivate Maps and restart the device. Still would like to know why this happened.

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect the issue with hardware graphic acceleration. Did this happen suddenly, or since long time ago? Also, I observed that you were using satellite mode, did this happen when you turn off the satellite mode? I found [a similar issue on Google Maps official support forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/vCRGDBSxMPU;context-place=topicsearchin/maps/green$20android), but it's unclear if it's the same or not. If you want, consider to post an update to that thread, or create a new thread with sufficient info on their forum.

Comment: Thank you ,its been that way since over a year as far as I can recall. Satellite mode on\off does not change anything. Im sure it has worked before, just dont know when it started turning green, havent been using it that much. I'll give the forum a shot.

Comment: The question is also going here : https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/maps/u7wwTeGttMg/s74fagzgo9cJ

Comment: @AHoneyBustard: did you try the suggested solution to uninstall updates and reinstall Google Map?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling updates, deactivating Maps and restarting the device worked.

Comment: You're the OP so consider editing your question to ask that "green part" rather than posting it here. In fact, because no other answer is good, you can overhaul your question and add the content you've mentioned here.

Comment: Made  it thanks, cant delete my answer though